# accessing 'session' from a filter

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using grails 2.5.x and adding some `PreAuthentication` to spring-security.

I'm trying to ferry request parameters into a PreAuth package, so I've created a filter that does it. Here's the class:

```
class PreAuthenticationRequestParametersFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
```

Here's the bootstrap:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    // injects request data for SAML login
    SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('preAuthRequestFilter', SecurityFilterPosition.PRE_AUTH_FILTER)
}
```

Finally, here's my bean config from `resources.groovy`:

```
preAuthRequestFilter(PreAuthenticationRequestParametersFilter) {
    authenticationManager = ref("authenticationManager")
}
```

I'd like to do some database lookups from the filter. However, it's barfing when I try to use my DAO (Hibernate) methods.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not obtain current Hibernate Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.methodMissing(GormStaticApi.groovy:105)
    com.mydomain.PreAuthenticationRequestParametersFilter.decodeXml(PreAuthenticationRequestParametersFilter.groovy:52)
```

I tried adding "`session = ref("session")`" to my filter in `resources.groovy`. That failed to compile.

**Is there a way to access my session/DAO at this level?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the Hibernate session, not the HTTP session. Grails uses the OpenSessionInView pattern, where it opens a Hibernate session and keeps it available until the request finishes, but Spring Security runs before Grails (in case it needs to block access) so there's no session automatically registered yet.

The simplest workaround for this is to wrap your code in a `withTransaction` block. This is a good idea anyway if you'll be writing to the database, but also avoids issues like you're seeing and also allows lazy loading to work. The domain class that you call `withTransaction` on has no impact so pick any one, e.g.

```
AnyDomainClass.withTransaction { status ->

  // GORM code here
}
```

Comment: answered in 20 minutes from Burt himself. I only need to read, but that's a great pattern to know- especially because it's helpful for the rest of my spring-security problem-solving.